# Filtering using TextWatcher on a ListView backed by a String ArrayAdapter returns empty results

Tags: android, listview, filter, android-arrayadapter, textwatcher

The following code returns 0 views in listview on entering any character in search `EditText`.
Following method is from activty class

```
private void setupList() {
    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactList);
    ArrayAdapter<Info> la = new MyListAdapter(this, mInfoList);
    lv.setAdapter(la);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    EditText edit =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbar);
    edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {
            Log.d("search", ""+text);
            ArrayAdapter<Info> la = (ArrayAdapter<Info>) lv.getAdapter();
            la.getFilter().filter(text);
            la.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

This is my adapter class

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Info> {
private Bitmap mDefaultProfilePic = null;
Context mContext = null;

public MyListAdapter(Context ctxt, ArrayList<Info> mFriendsAccounts) {
    super(ctxt, R.id.name, mFriendsAccounts);
    mContext = ctxt;

    mDefaultProfilePic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctxt.getResources(), R.drawable.face);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_view, null);
    }
    Info usr = getItem(position);
    ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(usr.Name);
    ((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.invite)).setTag(position);

    if (mImageBitmaps.get(position) != null) {
        ((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilePic)).setImageBitmap(mImageBitmaps.get(position));
    } else {
        ((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilePic)).setImageBitmap(mDefaultProfilePic);
    }

    return convertView;
}

}
```

Comment: Have you debugged and stepped through the code to see what exactly getAdapter returns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally fixed the problem. I had to override the `toString()` method in `Info` object. In my case filtering is based on `name` field so returned it through `toString()`. 

The filtering process calls the `toString()` on each object in the adapter.

Comment: userSeven7s i have the same problem but i can't show the problem. Could you be a bit explicit. Thx

Comment: have you posted a question here? please give the link. In my case,I overrode the `toString` method to return the info object data in string form.

Comment: Here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476645/filter-listview-i-cant-understand-filter-rule

Comment: I am still having an issue. Can you please elaborate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524417/listview-is-blank-while-using-getfilter-function

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#getAdapter%28%29) it says:

> The returned adapter might not be the same adapter passed to
>   setAdapter(ListAdapter) but might be a WrapperListAdapter

Could this have anything to do with your issue?

Comment: No. I added a member to hold the adapter but did not solve the issue.

Comment: Did you debug and step through the code to see exactly whats happening?

Comment: Yes. the listview is obtaining all the views(instead of only the filtered ones) from the adapter when i press any key.. but it doesnt show them in the listview. does it mean filter is the problem?