# Filter listview, i can't understand filter rule

Tags: android

i need apply a filter for a ListView. I read a lot of documentation but i can't understand the rule of the filter. The filter works but i don't know what are it doing.

I use this class:

```
public class ArtistasActivity extends Activity {

private EditText filterText = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View title = getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    View titleBar = (View) title.getParent();
    titleBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(181, 9, 97));

    setContentView(R.layout.artistas_l);

    final ListView m_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ListAdaptor adaptor = new ListAdaptor(this, R.layout.artistas_l, loadArtistas());

    m_listview.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    m_listview.setScrollingCacheEnabled(true);

    m_listview.setAdapter(adaptor);

    m_listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


    // Search

    filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {
            Log.d("search", ""+text);
            ListAdaptor adaptor = (ListAdaptor) m_listview.getAdapter();
            adaptor.getFilter().filter(text);
            adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

And ListAdaptor is typical:

```
    private class ListAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<Artista> {
    private ArrayList<Artista> artistas;

    public ListAdaptor(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Artista> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.artistas = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.artistas_list, null);
        }

        Object content = null;

        Artista o = artistas.get(position);

            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ArtistTopText);

            tt.setText(o.getNombre());

            v.setClickable(true);
            v.setFocusable(true);
            v.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);


        return v;
    }
}
```

The aplications works, and when write in the texteditor the list is filtered but when i put a R, appear names with Dani or Diego...

I override the toString method for only return de name.

```
    @Override
public String toString() {
    return this.nombre;
}
```

Thx for help !! Rgds

Comment: can u show all the fields in the Artista object..

Comment: if i inspect my adaptor, inside have Artistas, and inside artistas an array with elements and for element [nombre,destacado,foto,etc..]

Comment: I think the problem is that when i filter, the app identify the elements in the array. But print the First elements. For Example, if i write a R and in my array have three names that begin with r. Print the tree firs elements Alberto, America, Astucia... for example.

Comment: just comment out the `private ArrayList<Artista> artistas;`.. and replace `artistas.get(position);` with `getItem(position)`.. that will  fix it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to maintain the `aristas` array member, as you are already passing it to the super. In the `getView` method, get the item by calling `getItem(position)`.. This correction will fix the problem..

Comment: I am still having an issue: can you take a look please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524417/listview-is-blank-while-using-getfilter-function